# How to trace Windows Driver memory usage?

Tags: memory, drivers, azure, windows-server-2022

On multiple servers running Windows Server 2022 Azure edition there is a constantly growing page pool, increasing the committed memory to its maximum.
[Task Manager Memory usage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pOmuo.png)

Upon checking with poolmon, I noticed that the CLIP driver (ClipSp.sys) responsible for the licensing allocates more and more of paged memory, without releasing any of it.
[poolmon paging drivers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y1heo.png)

If we don't restart the systems for over 2 weeks, the page pool grows over 20GB

My question is, how best I can tell what does this driver do and why is it allocating that much memory?

Comment: I've got the same problem on an azure 2022 machine. Did you find any answers? Mine is a 2 core 16gb Standard E2ads v5.   I'm tempted to move to an intel based system just to see if this is some sort of AMD related issue...  I ran windows update yesterday to make sure everything was up to date and it's slowly growing.

Comment: Well I'm not sure exactly what I did... CLIP is still top of the list in poolmon but in perfmon the modified memory dropped from 200mb to 5mb (rebooted yesterday so it was low). I need to wait for more of a build up before I can redo what I did while paying closer attention...  I restarted some of the license services, reinstalled the windows admin center, and restarted some random services... something released the memory, at least in perfmon...

Edit: ran through all the stuff I did before and it didnt work this time...

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft admitted that there is a memory leak.
Currently there is a private patch they provide to customers that are affected.
We tested the fix in our company and it does solve the problem, indeed.

The problem is solved in KB article ID - KB5027225
https://products.support.services.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/june-13-2023-kb5027225-os-build-20348-1787-d2b4b682-935f-4afb-8de0-2265ae7d67e9

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).